# Upvoting a question on Area51 after breaking down vote totals results in incorrect display.

Tags: bug, area-51, vote-count

Although there are a lot of questions here about problems displaying up/down vote totals, I wasn't able to find one quite like this. Here are the steps to reproduce:

1. Visit [this question](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/43029/amateur-radio/43840#43840):

   [image]
2. Click the '8' to display vote totals:

   [image]
3. Upvote the question:

   [image]

   **Wait!** *81? Where did that come from?*
4. Now reload the page and click the '9' to display vote totals again.
5. Remove your upvote:

   [image]

I haven't tried reproducing this on any other Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Just a wild guess - but perhaps the problem is a `parseInt()` +/- 1 on the text content of the element containing the vote totals?